# jQuery - Don't hide div if I click inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep the current div visible if I click inside it. I want to hide the div only if I click anywhere on the page but the current div.

I already tried `e.stopPropagation();` but that breaks other click handlers I have inside the function.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/23/)**

```
var filterContainer = $(".js-filter-container");
var pageDocument = $(document);

$(document).on('click', '.js-show-filter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentFilter = $(this).next(filterContainer);
    currentFilter.toggle().css("z-index", 99);
    filterContainer.not(currentFilter).hide();

    pageDocument.click(function(){
        filterContainer.hide();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: lol You want to HIDE a div, but when that same div is clicked on, you want to UNHIDE it. How do you expect to click on something that is hidden?

Comment: @8protons no, he wants to keep the element visible when it's clicked *inside* and hide it when the user clicks anywhere *outside*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan "keep the element visible when it's clicked inside" so this equates to "do nothing when clicked inside" I mean, think about it, if your div is visible when you click in it, and it stays visible when you click in it, then you're not "keeping it visible", you're just "doing nothing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using with this solution:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!filterContainer.is(e.target) && filterContainer.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       filterContainer.hide();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/32/)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the event propagation, you can check whether the click was within the element by traversing upwards from the event.target, i.e. `$(e.target).closest()`.  (Checking just the event target itself would not work with sub-elements.)  The sample shown here binds to a specific element rather than a delegated document event, but it would work exactly the same:

```js
$('.catch').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.prevent').length) {
    // The click was somewhere inside .prevent, so do nothing
  } else {
    alert("Hide the element");
  }
});
```

```css
.prevent {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catch">
  Clicks here should fire the event.
  <div class="prevent">
    Clicks here should not fire the event.
    <div class="whatever">Neither should <b>clicks</b> on <i>child nodes</i>.</div>
    And not here.
  </div>
  But here, yes.
</div>
```

Comment: Overcomplicating things by trying to handle both the opener and closer in the same pass, mostly.  Fixed in https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/30/

Comment: (Incidentally, be careful about hanging too many delegated event handlers on `document` -- it can complicate your code, as here, when they start interfering with each other; and it causes the browser to fire too many events you don't need.   The only event that needs to be on `document` is the one to close the popup, which really should be bound only after the popup is opened (and then unbound when the popup is closed)... the rest should be bound directly to the opener links, or at least to a less distant parent element.

Answer (score 0):

there is two way:
The simplest: when clicking the div, call e.stopPropagation(), and copy all click handler you want (not the proper way, because you duplicate code...)

Or on your onclick function, get the cursor position, and close the div only if it is not inside the div:

```
pageDocument.click(function(e)
{
    //we get element position
    var startX = $(filterContainer).offset().left;  
    var startY = $(filterContainer).offset().top;

    var endX   = startX + $(filterContainer).outerWidth();
    var endY   = startY + $(filterContainer).outerHeight();

    //mouse pose relative to page (not window)
    var mouseX  = e.pageX;
    var mouseY  = e.pageY;


    if (!((mouseX > startX || mouseX < endX) && (mouseY > startY || mouseY < endY))) filterContainer.hide(); //if not on the container: remove it
});
```

Comment: Your second option would be the best bet.

Comment: I tried the second option too but it still doesn't work - https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/27/

Comment: Ok, I updated fiddle, it work better... (you didn't gave the 'e' arg to the function, and also you forgotten to remove (filterContainer).hide() at the begin of the onclick.

But the problem is that at each click, you declare an new handler, so you duplicate these ... Not the better way. You really want to close it at body click ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-show-filter', function(e) {
    $('.currentFilter').removeClass('currentFilter');
    var currentFilter = $(this).next('.js-filter-container');
    $('.js-filter-container:visible').hide();
    currentFilter.addClass('currentFilter');
    currentFilter.slideDown(500);
});

$('body').on('click', ':not(.currentFilter)', function(){
    $('.currentFilter').removeClass('currentFilter');
    $('.js-filter-container:visible').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2pr3xtxf/26/)

Check this [W3Schools How to](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) about accordions